# How to prevent user from adding more than 4 Tasks to a ToDo list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a todo list with very simple functionality.
People can enter a new task in the input box and delete the task after it's added and also cross it out when its clicked in order to check the task off.
I am trying to prevent the user from being able to add more than 4 tasks to the list.
When the user enters a new value and there are already 4 tasks in the to do list there should be an alert that says they cannot exceed 4 tasks. This is my code, for some reason it doesn't work (it lets users add as many tasks as they want :

````
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

var task= document.getElementById("task").childElementCount;

// remove to do

$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });  
    event.stopPropagation();
});



$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {

    if(event.which === 13 && task <= 4) {

        //    grabbing new tasks from user
            var newTask = $(this).val();
            $(this).val("");
            // create a new li and add to ul
            $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + newTask + "</li>")

    } else if (event.which === 13 && task > 4) {
        alert("you are trying to add too many tasks");
    }

}); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `task` isn't being updated, as you're assigning the value once and then always checking against that value - it's not updating dynamically

You could either count how many `li` are present in the list, inside the if statement to make sure it's always returning the correct amount though, or you could update the value of `task` after appending the new `li` to the page

```js
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

var task = document.getElementById("task").childElementCount;

// remove to do

$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {

  if (event.which === 13 && $('#task li').length <= 4) {

    //    grabbing new tasks from user
    var newTask = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    // create a new li and add to ul
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + newTask + "</li>")

  } else if (event.which === 13 && $('#task li').length > 4) {
    alert("you are trying to add too many tasks");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!It shows the alert now but after clicking ok, the new task is still added. How do I solve that?

Comment: If it's showing the alert it should be in the else section of your if / else - not sure what the issue could be without having more testable code; In your question I'm missing the HTML. I've updated my answer to include `$('#task li').length` in the first if as well, that might have been an issue - try with that change

Comment: Hey @Maayanp10, did you find a resolution to this issue?